Update channel config transaction
Im trying to update the app channel to add a new admin to the channel (as the previous one is going to expire)  but with the attached envelope I get the following error:
error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: unexpected missing policy  for item [Group]  /Channel
{
  "payload": {
    "header": {
      "channel_header": {
        "channel_id": "appchannel",
        "type": 2
      }
    },
    "data": {
      "config_update": {
        "channel_id": "appchannel",
        "isolated_data": {},
        "read_set": {
          "groups": {},
          "mod_policy": "",
          "policies": {},
          "values": {},
          "version": "0"
        },
        "write_set": {
          "groups": {
            "Application": {
              "groups": {
                "appMSP": {
                  "groups": {},
                  "mod_policy": "Admins",
                  "policies": {
                    "Admins": {
                      "mod_policy": "Admins",
                      "policy": {
                        "type": 1,
                        "value": {
                          "identities": [
                            {
                              "principal": {
                                "msp_identifier": "appMSP",
                                "role": "ADMIN"
                              },
                              "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                            }
                          ],
                          "rule": {
                            "n_out_of": {
                              "n": 1,
                              "rules": [
                                {
                                  "signed_by": 0
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          "version": 0
                        }
                      },
                      "version": "1"
                    },
                    "Readers": {
                      "mod_policy": "Admins",
                      "policy": {
                        "type": 1,
                        "value": {
                          "identities": [
                            {
                              "principal": {
                                "msp_identifier": "appMSP",
                                "role": "MEMBER"
                              },
                              "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                            }
                          ],
                          "rule": {
                            "n_out_of": {
                              "n": 1,
                              "rules": [
                                {
                                  "signed_by": 0
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          "version": 0
                        }
                      },
                      "version": "1"
                    },
                    "Writers": {
                      "mod_policy": "Admins",
                      "policy": {
                        "type": 1,
                        "value": {
                          "identities": [
                            {
                              "principal": {
                                "msp_identifier": "appMSP",
                                "role": "MEMBER"
                              },
                              "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                            }
                          ],
                          "rule": {
                            "n_out_of": {
                              "n": 1,
                              "rules": [
                                {
                                  "signed_by": 0
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          "version": 0
                        }
                      },
                      "version": "1"
                    }
                  },
                  "values": {
                    "MSP": {
                      "mod_policy": "Admins",
                      "value": {
                        "config": {
                          "admins": [
                            "admincert1",
                            "admincert2"
                          ],
                          "crypto_config": {
                            "identity_identifier_hash_function": "SHA256",
                            "signature_hash_family": "SHA2"
                          },
                          "fabric_node_ous": null,
                          "intermediate_certs": [],
                          "name": "appMSP",
                          "organizational_unit_identifiers": [],
                          "revocation_list": [],
                          "root_certs": [
                            "rootcert"
                          ],
                          "signing_identity": null,
                          "tls_intermediate_certs": [],
                          "tls_root_certs": [
                            "tlsrootcert"
                          ]
                        },
                        "type": 0
                      },
                      "version": "1"
                    }
                  },
                  "version": "1"
                }
              },
              "mod_policy": "Admins",
              "policies": {
                "Admins": {
                  "mod_policy": "Admins",
                  "policy": {
                    "type": 3,
                    "value": {
                      "rule": "ANY",
                      "sub_policy": "Admins"
                    }
                  },
                  "version": "1"
                },
                "Readers": {
                  "mod_policy": "Admins",
                  "policy": {
                    "type": 3,
                    "value": {
                      "rule": "ANY",
                      "sub_policy": "Readers"
                    }
                  },
                  "version": "1"
                },
                "Writers": {
                  "mod_policy": "Admins",
                  "policy": {
                    "type": 3,
                    "value": {
                      "rule": "ANY",
                      "sub_policy": "Writers"
                    }
                  },
                  "version": "1"
                }
              },
              "values": {},
              "version": "1"
            },
            "Orderer": {
              "groups": {
                "appMSP": {
                  "groups": {},
                  "mod_policy": "Admins",
                  "policies": {
                    "Admins": {
                      "mod_policy": "Admins",
                      "policy": {
                        "type": 1,
                        "value": {
                          "identities": [
                            {
                              "principal": {
                                "msp_identifier": "appMSP",
                                "role": "ADMIN"
                              },
                              "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                            }
                          ],
                          "rule": {
                            "n_out_of": {
                              "n": 1,
                              "rules": [
                                {
                                  "signed_by": 0
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          "version": 0
                        }
                      },
                      "version": "1"
                    },
                    "Readers": {
                      "mod_policy": "Admins",
                      "policy": {
                        "type": 1,
                        "value": {
                          "identities": [
                            {
                              "principal": {
                                "msp_identifier": "appMSP",
                                "role": "MEMBER"
                              },
                              "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                            }
                          ],
                          "rule": {
                            "n_out_of": {
                              "n": 1,
                              "rules": [
                                {
                                  "signed_by": 0
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          "version": 0
                        }
                      },
                      "version": "1"
                    },
                    "Writers": {
                      "mod_policy": "Admins",
                      "policy": {
                        "type": 1,
                        "value": {
                          "identities": [
                            {
                              "principal": {
                                "msp_identifier": "appMSP",
                                "role": "MEMBER"
                              },
                              "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                            }
                          ],
                          "rule": {
                            "n_out_of": {
                              "n": 1,
                              "rules": [
                                {
                                  "signed_by": 0
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          "version": 0
                        }
                      },
                      "version": "1"
                    }
                  },
                  "values": {
                    "MSP": {
                      "mod_policy": "Admins",
                      "value": {
                        "config": {
                          "admins": [
                            "admincert1",
                            "admincert2"
                          ],
                          "crypto_config": {
                            "identity_identifier_hash_function": "SHA256",
                            "signature_hash_family": "SHA2"
                          },
                          "fabric_node_ous": null,
                          "intermediate_certs": [],
                          "name": "appMSP",
                          "organizational_unit_identifiers": [],
                          "revocation_list": [],
                          "root_certs": [
                            "rootcert"
                          ],
                          "signing_identity": null,
                          "tls_intermediate_certs": [],
                          "tls_root_certs": [
                            "tlsrootcert"
                          ]
                        },
                        "type": 0
                      },
                      "version": "1"
                    }
                  },
                  "version": "1"
                }
              },
              "mod_policy": "Admins",
              "policies": {
                "Admins": {
                  "mod_policy": "Admins",
                  "policy": {
                    "type": 3,
                    "value": {
                      "rule": "MAJORITY",
                      "sub_policy": "Admins"
                    }
                  },
                  "version": "1"
                },
                "BlockValidation": {
                  "mod_policy": "Admins",
                  "policy": {
                    "type": 3,
                    "value": {
                      "rule": "ANY",
                      "sub_policy": "Writers"
                    }
                  },
                  "version": "1"
                },
                "Readers": {
                  "mod_policy": "Admins",
                  "policy": {
                    "type": 3,
                    "value": {
                      "rule": "ANY",
                      "sub_policy": "Readers"
                    }
                  },
                  "version": "1"
                },
                "Writers": {
                  "mod_policy": "Admins",
                  "policy": {
                    "type": 3,
                    "value": {
                      "rule": "ANY",
                      "sub_policy": "Writers"
                    }
                  },
                  "version": "1"
                }
              },
              "values": {
                "BatchSize": {
                  "mod_policy": "Admins",
                  "value": {
                    "absolute_max_bytes": 103809024,
                    "max_message_count": 10,
                    "preferred_max_bytes": 524288
                  },
                  "version": "1"
                },
                "BatchTimeout": {
                  "mod_policy": "Admins",
                  "value": {
                    "timeout": "300ms"
                  },
                  "version": "1"
                },
                "ChannelRestrictions": {
                  "mod_policy": "Admins",
                  "value": null,
                  "version": "1"
                },
                "ConsensusType": {
                  "mod_policy": "Admins",
                  "value": {
                    "metadata": {
                      "consenters": [
                        {
                          "client_tls_cert": "cert",
                          "host": "172.31.7.199",
                          "port": 7050,
                          "server_tls_cert": "cert"
                        },
                        {
                          "client_tls_cert": "cert",
                          "host": "172.31.15.15",
                          "port": 7050,
                          "server_tls_cert": "cert"
                        },
                        {
                          "client_tls_cert": "cert",
                          "host": "172.31.8.195",
                          "port": 7050,
                          "server_tls_cert": "cert"
                        }
                      ],
                      "options": {
                        "election_tick": 10,
                        "heartbeat_tick": 1,
                        "max_inflight_blocks": 5,
                        "snapshot_interval_size": 20971520,
                        "tick_interval": "500ms"
                      }
                    },
                    "state": "STATE_NORMAL",
                    "type": "etcdraft"
                  },
                  "version": "1"
                }
              },
              "version": "1"
            }
          },
          "mod_policy": "Admins",
          "policies": {
            "Admins": {
              "mod_policy": "Admins",
              "policy": {
                "type": 3,
                "value": {
                  "rule": "ANY",
                  "sub_policy": "Admins"
                }
              },
              "version": "1"
            },
            "Readers": {
              "mod_policy": "Admins",
              "policy": {
                "type": 3,
                "value": {
                  "rule": "ANY",
                  "sub_policy": "Readers"
                }
              },
              "version": "1"
            },
            "Writers": {
              "mod_policy": "Admins",
              "policy": {
                "type": 3,
                "value": {
                  "rule": "ANY",
                  "sub_policy": "Writers"
                }
              },
              "version": "1"
            }
          },
          "values": {
            "BlockDataHashingStructure": {
              "mod_policy": "Admins",
              "value": {
                "width": 4294967295
              },
              "version": "1"
            },
            "Consortium": {
              "mod_policy": "Admins",
              "value": {
                "name": "appConsortium"
              },
              "version": "1"
            },
            "HashingAlgorithm": {
              "mod_policy": "Admins",
              "value": {
                "name": "SHA256"
              },
              "version": "1"
            },
            "OrdererAddresses": {
              "mod_policy": "/Channel/Orderer/Admins",
              "value": {
                "addresses": [
                  "172.31.7.199:7050",
                  "172.31.15.15:7050",
                  "172.31.8.195:7050"
                ]
              },
              "version": "1"
            }
          },
          "version": "1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Im guessing that Im missing one of the policies but I do not see any missing.
